# Detect a public IP change in C#

Tags: c#, vpn

Using forms and OpenVPN

I'm trying to make a section of the UI change when a user is connected, so far I can get the original IP, but updating IP doesn't change.

I thought that trying to use a Task would fix it, but alas it did not and I'm at a loss. As I can't really find a lot of information about this kind of issue, though maybe I wasn't looking in the right spots.

```
public static void start()
{           
    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = //redacted;  
    startInfo.Arguments = // redacted;
    //startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    //startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    string orginalip = getipaddress();

    Task f = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (stopupdating == false)
        {
            string updatingip = getipaddressloop();

            if (orginalip == updatingip)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Connecting...");
                MessageBox.Show(orginalip + updatingip);
            }
            if (orginalip != updatingip)
            {
                stopupdating = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Connected UDP");
            }
        }
    });
}

static string getipaddressloop()
{
    while (stopupdating == false)
    {
        string address = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://ipv4.icanhazip.com/");
        return address;
    }
    string lastaddress = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://ipv4.icanhazip.com/");
    return lastaddress;
}

static string getipaddress()
{
    string address = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://ipv4.icanhazip.com/");
    return address;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, as its not clear, your application is client side and you're using UDP to connect to a server? You can't use external IP address as even a dynamic IP address will often be assigned by the ISP for a minimum period far longer than is of use. You appear to be using UDP which doesn't implement automated responses, as such you will need to sent a packet that actively triggers the server to send a response and then trigger a disconnect timeout if no reply is received within a set time frame.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need something like the following:

```cs
WebClient _client = new WebClient();

public static async void CheckForIpChange()
{
    orginalip = getipaddressloop();
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        string updatingip = getipaddressloop();

        if (orginalip == updatingip)
            MessageBox.Show("No Change");
        else
            break;
    });
    MessageBox.Show("New IP " + updatingip);
}

static string getipaddressloop()
{
    return _client.DownloadString("https://ipv4.icanhazip.com/");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was able to get this working after some modifications, and may have found the root of the issue.
When the loop attempts to download the string again via getipaddressloop() it does not "refresh" and always give the same value, I was able to get it working by using two different websites and only checking after 30 seconds, knowing I'd be connected by then